# foreach php-smarty help

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I have the php script as follows :

```
$sql = "
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            tbl_messages
        WHERE
            msg_sender_id = '$this->UM_index'
    ";
    $res = $this->db->returnArrayOfObject($sql);
    $this->assign_values('sent_messages',$res);
```

And in the templates I retrieved :

```
{foreach name = feach key = indx item = k from = $sent_messages}
{$k->msg_sender_id}
{$k->msg_subject}
{/forach}
```

I can retriev the above two fields. But I want to retrieve the `message_sender_name` for the field `sender_id` which can be obtained from a function `getDetails($id)`.

My question is how can I assign the `sender_name` fields (which is a array) to my smarty template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want also want to be able to have the message_sender_name, wich is returned by the function getDetails($id)?

You will have to loop trough your results, and fetch the message_sender_name for each row. Something like this:

```
$arrResults = array();
while ($res = $this->db->returnArrayOfObject($sql)))
{
  $res['msg_sender_name'] = getDetails($res['msg_sender_id']);
  $arrResults[] = $res;
}
$this->assign_values('sent_messages',$arrResults);
```

If I'm right, you can now access the sender_name via `{$k->msg_sender_name}` in your template-file.

But I would suggest that you use a JOIN in your SQL-statement, so you don't have to make another request for the sender_name.

Comment: Thanks fro replying..but it shows "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\social\PEAR\pager\Jumping.php on line 152" !!!

Comment: Can you edit your post with the content of your getDetail()-function and the code from Jumping.php where the error comes from?

Comment: I used JOIN the tables as you suggested and it is working now . Thanks